# Visa Requirements for Musandam from Dubai

Tags: visas, uae, oman

We are Indian passport holders. Planning to visit Musandam (Oman) from Dubai on a guided tour. I had a few questions for anyone who has done this trip:

1. Do we need an Oman visa?
2. Do we need a multiple entry visa for UAE, in order to return to Dubai?
3. If we self drive, do rental companies in Dubai allow taking cars to Musandam?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need an Oman visa?

No, you are [allowed](https://www.fm.gov.om/visitors/entry-visas/) visa-free for 14 days in Oman

> India

> Do we need a multiple entry visa for UAE, in order to return to Dubai?

Yes, you will

> If we self drive, do rental companies in Dubai allow taking cars to Musandam?

This will highly depend on the company